# how to bound recurrence?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I am writing a simple library using recursive data structures like BST. How do I bound recursive functions like search, insert or postorder print in an elegant manner.

```
void print_postorder(BST_NODE* node)
{
     if (node == NULL)
        return;

     print_postorder(node->left);
     print_postorder(node->right);

     cout<<node->key<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Does your function not work?

Comment: What functionality do you expect when you bound a recursive function?  How is it different from what you've written?

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that you are trying to [map a function to your data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)). That is, instead of printing each node, you would like to execute an arbitrary function on each node recursively. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean "How to print it with indentation reflecting your tree structure instead of printing a 'flat' column of keys?"

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux My function works. However the requirement for this library is no unbounded recurrence. There is nothing about mapping function recursively. That is a simple lib without such tricks.

Comment: @Misery Recursive functions on recursive data are implicitly bound by the data. If you need an explicit boundary, see the answer below.

Comment: What do you expect it to do when it reaches the limit? Give up with an error? Skip part of the work? Switch to a different algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to limit the depth of your call stack (say, only allow for N recursive calls).

The easiest way to do this would be to simply pass the current depth of your call stack as a const parameter.
Your code would become:

```
void print_postorder(BST_NODE* node, const unsigned int call_depth)
{
     if (node == NULL || call_depth > SOME_THRESHOLD)
        return;

     print_postorder(node->left, call_depth + 1);
     print_postorder(node->right, call_depth + 1);

     cout<<node->key<<endl;
}
```

Note that SOME_THRESHOLD must have a value. You can hardcode it in the function (bad) or define it as a static constant (better).

Your first call would go from being `print_postorder(node)` to `print_postorder(node, 0)`.

Comment: Hmmm... that's another way to see it. Let's see if whoever asked comments my answer to see if it helped.